# html onload not triggering after ajax call in Internet Explorer,

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have an ajax call to a php script which runs some things on the server. When this is completed I want to make php call out a javascript function. To do this I used this.

```
//This line works in chrome and firefox.
echo "<style onload='test()'></style>";
//this one doesnt work after an ajax call.
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>test()</script>";
```

This line works and triggers in chrome and firefox, but not in internet explorer.

**So my question is, is there a solution or an alternative for this?**
Is there a way to call a new javascript function after an ajax call depending on the result of the ajax call? (not just succes or failure)

Ill explain my system a bit more for extra information. I store a lot of my data in a session.

I got my code here and stripped it from extra or useless code for this example, during this spelling errors, parse errors or other syntax errors might have occurred **this is not the problem** though.

```
//Index.php
<head><script src='location' type='text/javascript'></script></head>
<body>
   <div id='container'>
      <div id='head'></div>
      <div id='content'></div>
   </div>
   <div id='hidden'></div> // this div is hidden for js feedback
   <script type='text/javascript'>loadContent();</script>
</body>

//javascript file
function loadContent(){
    //my ajax function works it requires 3 variables
    //url to php, div that will be changed, array with post variables.
    Ajax("urltophp", "hidden", Array(""));
}

function loadHome(){
    Ajax("urltophp2", "head", Array("headhome"));
    Ajax("urltophp2", "cont", Array("conthome"));
}

function loadLogin(){
    Ajax("urltophp2", "head", Array("headlogin"));
    Ajax("urltophp2", "cont", Array("contlogin"));
}

function test(){
    alert("test"); //for testing
}

//then urltophp
$ses = $_SESSION("ses"); //this is an object of class SESSION
$timeout = $ses->getTimeout();
$loggedin = $ses->getLoggedin();
//THIS WORKS IN CHROME AND FIREFOX NOT IN IE.
if(time() - $timeout < 3600){  //if an hour hasnt passed since last action.
    if($loggedin){             //if user was logged in.   
        echo "<style onload='loadHome()'></style>";
    }else{
        echo "<style onload='loadLogin()'></style>";
    }
}

//urltophp2
$p = $_POST['var1'];
$ses = $_SESSION["ses"];
//used for checking if user is logged in before loading page 
//in case of cross-site scripting. left out in this example.
$loggedin = $ses->getloggedin();
switch($p){
    case "headhome":
    echo $homehead;  //assume I loaded this from a file.
    break;
    case "conthome":
    echo $conthead;  //assume the same.
    break;
    etc. for all options.
}
```

Thanks in advance kpp.

Comment: i think `onload` is not the attribute of `style` tag

Comment: Move `onload='test()'` to the body tag

Comment: @colburton I tried that, didnt work on any browser. The biggest problem is that I try to execute javascript after the dom has been loaded and IE tells me that's not possible while the others are like sure go ahead

Answer (score 0):

*Is there a way to call a new javascript function after an ajax call depending on the result of the ajax call?*

Yes.

```
$.get("test.php", function(data) {
    if (data.prop === "A") {
        foo();
    } else {
        bar();
    }
});
```

**Note:** Obviously I'm using jQuery here.

Comment: I was just looking into this, but the only question that remains is how do I do that check right there, like can I make my php return like 1, 2 or 3 and yet still echo other things in a div? or do I have to make php echo 1, 2, 3 and then use that result to echo other things in a div?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. To pass data from PHP to JS you should use the built-in `json_encode` function. Then just echo out the result of the function like this `<script>var jsondata = <?php echo data ?> </script>`.

Comment: I formulated my question wrong, I pretty much meant where does `data.prop` come from. Is this what you echo in your php or what you return.